# Save multiple textbox values to database

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to save multiple textbox values to database into multiple rows. My form is as follows

textbox1 texbox 2  ---- row 1 in database

textbox3 textbox 4  ------row 2 in database

edit: I should clarify that textbox 1 and texbox 3 are in the same column and using the same param1

Ive been to save single values before using

```
 cnn.Open();
    SqlTransaction tran = cnn.BeginTransaction();
    cmd.Connection = cnn;
    cmd.Transaction = tran;
    cmd.CommandText = "stored procedure";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = cnn;
    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@param1", SqlDbType.Int);
    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@param2", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
```

Comment: Post the stored procedure code along with the table schema

Comment: I should clarify that textbox 1 and texbox 3 are in the same column and using the same param1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand properly, try it

```
SqlTransaction tran = cnn.BeginTransaction();
cmd.Connection = cnn;
cmd.Transaction = tran;
cmd.CommandText = "stored procedure";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = cnn;
for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
{
    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@param1", SqlDbType.Int);
    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@param2", SqlDbType.Int);
    if( i == 0 )
    {
       p1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text.Trim());     // row 1 in database
       p2.Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text.Trim());    // row 1 in database
    }
    else
    {
       p1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text.Trim());     // row 2 in database
       p2.Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text.Trim());   // row 2 in database
    }
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Execute the query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code

```
SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@param1", SqlDbType.Int);
 p1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text.Trim());
 SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@param2", SqlDbType.Int);
 p2.Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text.Trim());
```